# passing value in same page with ajax

Tags: php, javascript

I am newbie on ajax. My case is, i want to passing value on same page so if i click on selected the value pass to upper

[image]

on my pure php code like this

```
<?php include('connect.php');

$query="SELECT barang_id, nama, stok, AuUser,AuDate FROM barang";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" >
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">No.</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Barang ID</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Nama</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Stock</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">AuUser</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">AuDate</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Select</font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;$j=1;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"barang_id");
$f2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"nama");
$f3 = mysql_result($result,$i,"stok");
$f4 = mysql_result($result,$i,"auuser");
$f5 = mysql_result($result,$i,"audate");

?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $j; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td> 
<td><a href="data.php?id=<?php echo $f1;?>&nama=<?php echo $f2;?>&stok=<?php echo $f3;?>&auuser=<?php echo $f4;?>&audate=<?php echo $f5;?>">Selected</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++; $j = $j + 1;
}?>
<?php

$id1 = ($_GET['id']) ;
$nama1 = ($_GET['nama']) ;
$stok1 = ($_GET['stok']);
$auuser1 = ($_GET['auuser']);
$audate1 = ($_GET['audate']) ;

?>
<div class="tengah">
    <form action="doupload.php" method="post">
        <div class="kiri">ID </div>
        <div class="kanan"><input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id1;?>"/> </div>
        <div class="kiri">nama </div> 
        <div class="kanan"><input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" value="<?php echo $nama1;?>"/></div>
        <div class="kiri"> stock </div>
        <div class="kanan"><input type="text" name="stok" id="stok" value="<?php echo $stok1;?><?php echo $id1;?>"/></div>
        <div class="kiri">auuser </div>
        <div class="kanan"><input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $auuser1;?>"/></div>
        <div class="kiri">audate </div>
        <div class="kanan"><input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo $audate1;?>"/></div>

        <div class="kiri"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
        <div class="kanan"><input name="Reset" type="reset" value="cancel" /></div>
    </form>
    <div id="insert_response"></div>
</div>
```

here are the problems is i wanted using ajax so when i click selected on table.
The value passing on top without loading.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the Ajax part of the code?

Comment: I dont know how to using ajax. so i am asking about it

Comment: Why would you need ajax for this?

Comment: So i the page doesn't need to loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use AJAX as you don't have to load the data from an external file. You can just use some javascript to populate the form. There are more efficient ways to do it then the code below, but here's a quick and dirty answer...

Oh, and I did the javascript in jquery because it makes things easier. But the same can be done in pure javascript.

For your HTML/PHP code, change the a tag to use onclick instead of href, and call a javascript function:

```
<a onclick="updateForm('<?php echo '$f1'?>','<?php echo '$f2'?>','<?php echo '$f3'?>','<?php echo '$f4'?>','<?php echo '$f5'?>');">Selected</a>
```

Then, create a javascript function on the same page that looks like this:

```
<script>

function updateForm(id, nama, stok, user,date){
    $('#id').val(id);
    $('#nama').val(name);
    $('#stok').val(stok);
    $('#user').val(user);
    $('#date').val(date);
}

</script>
```

If you don't want to use jquery, I think the equivalent of $('#id').val(id) is document.getElementById('id').value = id;